# Is it safe to (can I) use `HttpError` from 'admin-on-rest/lib/util/HttpError'?

Tags: admin-on-rest

My API provider is sending error messages in the `response.body` as a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) as plain text and I need to get admin-on-rest to display those messages to the end user.

I'm planning to do so like this:

```
import HttpError from 'admin-on-rest/lib/util/HttpError'
import _ from 'lodash';

function handleError(response) {
  if (_.isFunction(response.text)) {
    const statusText = response.statusText;
    const status = response.status;
    return response.text().then(text => { // get the text from the ReadableStream
      return Promise.reject(new HttpError( text || statusText, status));
    });
  } else { throw new Error(response.statusText); }
}
```

And in my custom REST Client

```
//...
if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
    return handleError(response);
}
//...
```

But I feel that accessing to `HttpError` directly through `'admin-on-rest/lib/util/HttpError'` intead of `'admin-on-rest'` is insecure because if the internal implementation changes (or there is a refactor of the internal classes of the framework, etc) my implementation will fail.

I **cannot** do `import HttpError from 'admin-on-rest/lib/util/HttpError'` because it doesn't work that way. I get `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_admin_on_rest___default.a is not a constructor`

- So, would be safe to import `HttpError` like this or not: `import HttpError from 'admin-on-rest/lib/util/HttpError'`?
- If no, would it be any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple(er) and safe(er) alternative can be just **not** to **use** **`HttpError`** at all.

Instead do `Promise.reject` with a **simple object** as argument, which contains a `message` and `status` properties like this:

```
//...
return response.text().then(text => {
  return Promise.reject({message: text || statusText, status: status});
});
//...
```